# When is an accusation synonymous with asking a question?

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrases, expressions, differences

Can an accusation be considered (implicitly) as asking a question?

As an example:
Accusation: “You’re pretending to be a police officer”
Question: “Are you pretending to be a policy officer?”

Can one say the accusation is implying the question? Or the same as asking a question?
Or is it something else?

Comment: Depending on the context almost anything can imply a question, including declarative statements. Similarly, what sounds like a question can actually be a command or declarative statement, like "Didn't I tell you to clean your bedroom?" In the case of a police officer making an accusation, they're may not be asking a question, they may be telling you that you're being charged or arrested, but in some cases it would be a question, e.g. a parent telling a child "I gave you a new pencil yesterday", meaning "What happened to it?" You could call it "implying a question".

Comment: Why the down votes??

Comment: @StuartF Your comment should be given as an answer.  I like it very much and would except it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I say, "You are a liar," I'm making a declarative statement. This is the most basic form of [accusation](https://www.etymonline.com/word/accusation). You might try to contradict that statement by saying, "No, I am not a liar," but that doesn't mean I was asking a question.